# Find control in devexpress gridview Templates DetailRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, findcontrol

I want to find control  in my gridview.Template detail row by id

```
        bool IsAllAud = false;
        var item = (CheckBox)VendorsGrid.Templates.DetailRow.FindControl("CBIsAllAudience");
        IsAllAud = item.Checked;
        if (IsAllAud)
        {

        }
```

```html
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="rt" ClientInstanceName="rt" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="rtt" KeyFieldName="ID" Width="100%">
            <SettingsDetail AllowOnlyOneMasterRowExpanded="true" />
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Name" />
            </Columns>
            <Templates>
                <DetailRow>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CBIsAllAudience" runat="server" />
...
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more explanation of the problem you are having? What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: var item = (CheckBox)VendorsGrid.Templates.DetailRow.FindControl("CBIsAllAudience");

this is what I need to do, but it's compilation error as VendorsGrid.Templates.DetailRow has no FindControl() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is DetailRow you will need to call [ASPxGridView.FindDetailRowTemplateControl Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindDetailRowTemplateControltopic)

var item = VendorsGrid.FindDetailRowTemplateControl(index, "CBIsAllAudience");

Answer (score 2):

In the control event Just write this code

```
{
 for (int i = 0; i < gvVndInvoiceDevExp.VisibleRowCount ; i++)
            {
                GridViewDataColumn col1 = gvVndInvoiceDevExp.Columns[0] as GridViewDataColumn;
                GridViewDataColumn col2 = gvVndInvoiceDevExp.Columns[8] as GridViewDataColumn;
                CheckBox chk = gvVndInvoiceDevExp.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, col1, "chk") as CheckBox;
                ASPxCheckBox chkIsVal = gvVndInvoiceDevExp.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, col2, "chkIsVal") as ASPxCheckBox;

                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    chkIsVal.Enabled = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    chkIsVal.Enabled = false;

                }

            }
}
```